# Iterate over 'Map' object is concurrent safe in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, concurrency, iteration

In Node js I have a `Map` object that multiple asynchronous functions add values to it, everything is working fine. But now i'm creating an cleanup function that, every fixed interval will iterate over that Map to remove expired records, i'm now using the `forEach` function, putting the expired records in another array, then removing the array records one-by-one, my question is: It's safe to run the `forEach` function while other asynchronous tasks insert records in the map?

Comment: Please add some relevant piece of code so we can be more precise in answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js runs in one thread. There is no way to make to parallel task (aside child-process etc). So yeah it's safe.